# Swift observer on Objective-C singleton is not triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager, key-value-observing

**EDIT**: Sorry, the code as it is presented does work, it just that the debug notification occurred at a different place than I was expecting it. Read carefully kids.

As of right now, I have an Objective-C singleton for CLLocationManager that is being observed by a Swift class. I have been able to successfully compile and add the observer onto the singleton and been able to get the location from the singleton when viewDidLoad is triggered. I have also successfully used the singleton in other classes so I do not believe the singleton itself is the issue. The only thing that is not working is when I trigger an update for the location, the observer on the Swift class does not respond. Code is as follows

For convenience, the code is also available on Github

[Singleton](https://github.com/xinkecf35/DawnPlus/blob/settings/TrafficAlarmClock/LocationFetch.m)

[Swift Class](https://github.com/xinkecf35/DawnPlus/blob/settings/TrafficAlarmClock/SwiftClasses/AddressViewController.swift)

Singleton

```
+(LocationFetch *) sharedInstance {
    static LocationFetch *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc]init];
        });
    return instance;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        //Request Authorization
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)startingUpdatingLocation {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");
}
-(void)stopUpdatingLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     NSLog(@"Stopping Location Updates");
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location updates failed with %@", error);
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

    //self.currentLocation = location;
    [self setCurrentLocation:location];
    NSLog(@"LocationFetch sharedInstance: Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Swift Class

```
class AddressViewController: UIViewController {
    //Properties
    var latitude:Double = 0
    var longitude:Double = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        latitude = LocationFetch.sharedInstance().latitude
        longitude = LocationFetch.sharedInstance().longitude
        LocationFetch.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(LocationFetch.currentLocation), options: .new, context: nil)
        debugPrint("\(self) current location is: \(latitude), \(longitude)")

    }
    deinit {
        LocationFetch.sharedInstance().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(LocationFetch.currentLocation))
    }

    //Key-Value Observe for LocationFetch(myLocation)
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == #keyPath(LocationFetch.currentLocation) {
            latitude = LocationFetch.sharedInstance().latitude
            longitude = LocationFetch.sharedInstance().longitude
            debugPrint("\(self) updated current location is: \(latitude), \(longitude)")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried that originally, try to register the observer and got a crash and was informed that property that stored the reference was not KVC compliant

Comment: Tried that, again it did not work. I will admit this is a little unusual as the singleton is implemented in Objective-C and the observer is being added in a ViewController that is implemented in Swift. The Singleton is bridged

Comment: Maybe I'd do something like implement the observing myself if the KVO is such pain...something like storing array of objects conforming to some protocol, or array of closures/block that will be called on location update...if doing so, remember to remove them when objects get dealloced...

Comment: NSNotificationCenter does that for you out of the box.  No need to re-invent the wheel.  By the way, I created a quick test app and your code works for me as is, except I removed the distance filter as that causes a location services error

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, sorry for my loose terminology. I understand I do not observe the whole object but rather a specific property. I know that KVO can succeed with this object and property as I literally used it somewhere else. I just trying to understand why this particular observer would not work.

Comment: Like I said, your code works for me.  The only  thing I removed is the distance filter, then I simulated a freeway drive and got numerous updates

Comment: So the observer on the singleton does work. Huh, that really weird because I swore it did not.

Comment: Oh wait, I was a dingus, I had expected the debug output for the observer to be at the very bottom. Whoops. Anyway, thanks for all the help @Paulw11